# Linking CSS to Taggle.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tagging

I am fairly new to CSS and javascript. I have been trying to implement the Tagging system as provided in Taggle.js (http://sean.is/poppin/tags).

Using this script :

```
  <html>
  <body>
    Hello!! <br>
    <form id="form1" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/post">
      <fieldset>
        Tags:
        <div id ="freeTags" ></div>
        <p id='tag'></p><br><br>
     </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script src="./node_modules/taggle/assets/js/taggle.js"></script>
    <script>
    var text = document.getElementById('tag');
    new Taggle('freeTags', {
      onTagAdd: function(event, tag) {
        text.innerHTML = "You just added " + tag;
      },
      onTagRemove: function(event, tag) {
        text.innerHTML = "You just removed "+ tag;
      },
      duplicateTagClass : "bounce"

    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am unable to get the same effect as on the website (fancy text box) instead what I have been getting is this:

[image]

And it is also not implementing the 'bounce' function although I installed bounce.js using bower.

I think it must be the issue of CSS linkage to HTML. Can any one help in untangling this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for taggle says the bounce effect is handled by the taggle.css file ... which your code example above doesn't include. Suggest this file also deals with styling of the elements youve said are missing. So just link this file in your document  and re - test.

Find the CSS file in the repo you link to above the folder assets/css/ ([find here](https://github.com/okcoker/taggle.js/tree/master/assets/css)), and save either taggle.css or taggle.min.css (for production) to your server and add the following to your page immediately after the `<html>` opening tag...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/taggle.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- your content... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But it still does not show that rectangular box around the text area. What is it that I am missing in my HTML?

Comment: @mousecoder - looking at the taggle stylesheet all you need to do is add `class="textarea input"` to `<div id="freeTags">` ... this will apply the text area styling. That heavy border you're probably seeing is the native rendering of the `<fieldset>` element you have wrapped it all with - you'll have to re-style this with your own CSS as it's out of the scope of the taggle plugin's CSS.

Comment: I should add too that, all the `<br>` tags you've added are going to have an impact of course to spacing inside that div - so if it looks unusual, strip these out and you'll see the element as intended